# Why interpolation gives me NANi values

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have a vector `X =   [1.4104 - 0.6176i  -0.5766 + 0.3408i];` I need to run interpolation into 1:4:8 using the command `interp1` in Matlab, but that gives me NANi results, as below:

```
X =   [1.4104 - 0.6176i  -0.5766 + 0.3408i];
Y = interp1(1:4:8 , X , 1:8)
```

The results of vector Y is  `1.4104 - 0.6176i   0.9137 - 0.3780i   0.4169 - 0.1384i  -0.0798 + 0.1012i  -0.5766 + 0.3408i      NaN +    NaNi  NaN +    NaNi      NaN +    NaNi`

So, what's the problem in that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the interpolation is undefined at its bound. `X` if of length 2 and the corresponding *time/position* values are `1:4:8` = `[1,5]`. And now, you want to get a result at time/position `1:8` = `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]`. How does the interpolator should now what is at `[6 7 8]` as it cannot extrapolate.

What you maybe wanted to do is

```
Y = interp1(0:4:8 , X , 1:8)
```

(starting at `0` to obtain `[0 4 8]`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply ... Actually I have a vector of size (8,1) , and its values 1:4:end are known which are X in my case.  So, I want to interpolate these two values which represents 1:4:end into the whole vector.  how can I do it?

Comment: note that if the values of `1:4:end`=`1:4:8` are known, the values are known at the indices `[1,5]` and nowhere else. If you want to do linear extrapolation add `'linear', 'extrap'` to `interp1` => `interp1(1:4:8 , X , 1:8,'linear', 'extrap') `